# Add a mature content warning to first-time visitors

Tags: functions, ip

I would like to ask visitors if they are 18+ at the first visit to my blog.
If they click yes, they access the blog normally and next time they will not be asked.
If they click no, they access an info page, and they shouldn't have the opportunity to retract. I want to record the IP so even if they reload or clear cookies, they will not be asked again, just be redirected to the no-no page.

Is this possible? Should I rename WP's index.php to something else, or this can be made directly inside index.php?

Any example code I can base on to achieve it?

Comment: **Everything is POSSIBLE** [full stop] - so just get to the procedure - you have to record visitor's IP to database, so search for that first. Now you got that, so search for the *how to do pop up*. ...now you got it. And I'm afraid it's not specific to WordPress, so it's an off-topic here.

Comment: I can figure out how to record the IP on the database, but I don't want a popup, I want to have the question on the main page if it is the first visit, and I seen it's not recommended to rename index.php for the WP blog (and don't want to move it inside a folder due to already configured plugins). What's hard for me is the actual code to make the comparison of the IP, and how to make the proper structure for the redirect to be successful, without disturbing SEO. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a simple code like this in your `header.php`: `$getIP = ...; $getDBIP = ...; if($getIP !== $getDBIP) { /* show the warning */ } else {` ...it's an unexpected end here in `header.php`, so end the braces in `footer.php` like that `} //endif`. I'm afraid I din't implemented it, this is what I can think now.

Comment: You should rephrase your question: "How to show one time message/content to visitors?" That might include Cookies, redirects, DB CRUD requests, etc. Please also do some research and show (in code) where you are stuck and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question directly, but there are a few big issues you have to address here. Adult sites get a lot of traffic (usually a lot of fake, hacker and spam traffic), which means a lot of wasted space in your db and slower loading times if you are going to make use of ip addresses to save a first time visit.

Think about it, if recieved 100 000 unique hits, you will have 100 000 ip addresses saved. This translates to 100 000 ip addresses that needs to be checked on **every** page load. With already slow serving times due to large adult material being loaded, this will only frustate the end user

Cookies does seem to be a better idea, although some countries have very strict regulations about cookies and adult material. This is frankly something that you will need to research yourself and make sure your site is compliant with all regulations

I really don't think there is any real solution to this problem, yes, saving ip addresses might be the safest, but it is the slowest.

A possible solution might be to make use of a static frontpage which serves as a notice and warning page. You then make use of referrers to check from where a specific page was referred from (not 100% reliable). If a page was referred from any page outside the site or it was directly accessed or there is no referrer, redirect the user to the static front page. You can then set a custom query_vars in all your links that will serves as a reliable internal referrer.

On every page load you then just simply check if the specific query_vars is set in the url, and if it is, load the specific page.

This is just one option to explore and definitely need much more planning and a lot of testing to find the best option